# Use Comment In UI

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to use UE4's comment function in the UI window of my personal project. It has been implemented to some extent, but there is a problem with Z-order. We put one Canvas and added a comment on it, but there is no problem setting the Z-order in the comment itself. When I put a new comment or something else on top of it, I want to set the Z-order of the title part of the comment and the box part below it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Z-ordering of comments in any Blueprint is based on the order of creation.
Slate is slow enough, lets not try to add to the delay.

While the C++ code has a z-order argument, exposing it as a configurable object would add additional delays.

---

Design your code on paper first (as my first programming teacher taught me to do), then implement it.

Why should the existing code be modified to match your programming style?

---

### Otherwise:

Simply delete all commented blocks and reorganize...